# Can I use a function from parent process in the child process?

Tags: python, unix, tkinter, multiprocessing

I made a GUI in python that is started through a menu item from an existing application. The existing app has a function that takes a screenshot of the app's current window. I want to call that function from the GUI i created. Is there some method that i can just do

```
id = os.getppid()
id.parent_function()
```

and use the parent process function in the child process?

I'm coding in unix environment.

Comment: The functions are not exclusive to the different processes, but can be called freely from any process (as long as you are not relying on some strange global states).

Comment: So how would i call that function? Make an object of parent process? If so, how?

Comment: A process is not an object. These are different things. But maybe you start your child process by calling a `.start()` method of a newly created object? Also, is your "parent function" an object method? Then you need an object of that kind to call it...

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult to say without knowing what's going on with the rest of your program. Could you please review this and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve